# Error in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

my .html code:

```
<table id="unique_id_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Base Url</th>
        <th>Statistics Ur</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#unique_id_table').DataTable({
        });
    })
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
```

Why?

I copied it from another of my page, where everything worked

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should know how to do is how to Google something. An error like that makes it very easy to find people with the same issue.

According to this: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20273/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined

You are missing the `thead` and `tbody` tags. It seems they are required.

```
<table id="unique_id_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Base Url</th>
            <th>Statistics Ur</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And from the [official documentation with the same prerequisites](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/).

Comment: No, I have thead and tbody

Comment: Not according to your code in the OP. I don't see them.